# Do lightmaps only work for static scenes?

Tags: javascript, rendering, light, babylonjs

Am I understanding correctly that lightmaps are static images that overlay onto a texture to add light? Can they be gifs that animate as well?

When using a lightmap, does it always display the same way each time? Meaning, does it interact with the objects in your scene like a shadow (created with a lightmap) following a ball (rendered in realtime)?

Also, how do you create the lightmap file? I'm using Babylon.js, so would I set up a scene then instead of rendering to a canvas I would render to a createLightmap function?

Answer (score 0):

lightmaps are for static lightning (because you are basically baking the amount of light received per objects.

So yes, as this is static it will always behave the same.

Most of the time, you can use Blender, 3dsmax or Maya to generate your lightmaps.

Unity works as well: https://doc.babylonjs.com/resources/exporter#lightmap-baking-options